# Regex to allow only one punctuation character in Java string

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse raw data and allow strings that can contain alphabets and ONLY one punctuation character.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class ProcessRawData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myData = "Australia India# America@!";
    ProcessRawData data = new ProcessRawData();
    data.process(myData);

}

public void process(String rawData) {
    String[] splitData = rawData.split(" ");
    for (String s : splitData) {
        System.out.println("My Data Elements: " + s);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{Alpha}\\p{Punct}]*$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Allowed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

}

It prints below,

```
My Data Elements: Australia
Allowed
My Data Elements: India#
Allowed
My Data Elements: America@!
Allowed
```

Expected is it should NOT print **America@!** as it contains more than one punctuation character.

I guess I might need to use quantifiers, but not sure where to place them so that it will allow ONLY one punctuation character?

Can someone help?

Comment: See [`"^(?!.*\\p{Punct}{2})[\\p{Punct}\\p{Alpha}]+$"`](https://regex101.com/r/nB8lM0/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That regex would allow `a#b$c`, which has 2 special characters, but they are not together.

Comment: I thought two consecutive are not allowed. If just 2 in all string non-consecutively, then `"^(?!(?:\\P{Punct}*\\p{Punct}){2})[\\p{Punct}\\p{Alpha}]+$"` should help, or better:  `^\\p{Alpha}*(?:\\p{Punct}\\p{Alpha}*)?$`. I did not post since I see a discrepancy between the title and the examples.

Comment: @WebNoob Please check my comment and let me know what pattern from the above ones works for you. Something should.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, the 2nd regex worked for what I was looking for.

Comment: @WebNoob I posted the answer with an explanation. Can't prepare a regex demo on a mobile, I will add it as a comment once I get to my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile your [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) *outside* the loop.

When using [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--), there's no need for `^` and `$`, since it'll match against the entire string anyway.

If you need *at most* one punctuation character, you need to match a single *optional* punctuation character, preceded and/or followed by optional alphabet characters.

Note that using `\\p{Alpha}` and `\\p{Punct}` excludes digits. No digit will be allowed. If you want to consider a digit as a special character, replace `\\p{Punct}` with `\\P{Alpha}` (uppercase P means *not* Alpha).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    process("Australia India# Amer$ca America@! America1");
}
public static void process(String rawData) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}*\\p{Punct}?\\p{Alpha}*");
    for (String s : rawData.split(" ")) {
        System.out.println("My Data Elements: " + s);
        if (pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Allowed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
My Data Elements: Australia
Allowed
My Data Elements: India#
Allowed
My Data Elements: Amer$ca
Allowed
My Data Elements: America@!
Not allowed
My Data Elements: America1
Not allowed
```

Comment: shouldn't "America1" be allowed?

Comment: @erolkaya84 *"can contain **alphabets** and ONLY one **special** character"* If you categorize a digit as a special character, then yes, but it's not usually categorized that way. Which is why I pointed it out in the 4th paragraph, just to be sure OP was aware of it.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot for the tips and solution. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^\\p{Alpha}*(?:\\p{Punct}\\p{Alpha}*)?$
```

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\\p{Alpha}*` - zero or more letters
- `(?:\\p{Punct}\\p{Alpha}*)?` - one or zero (due to the `?` quantifier) sequences of:

  - `\\p{Punct}` - a single occurrence of a punctuation symbol
  - `\\p{Alpha}*` - zero or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

Using it with `String#matches` will allow dropping the `^` and `$` anchors since the pattern will then be anchored by default:

```
if (input.matches("\\p{Alpha}*(?:\\p{Punct}\\p{Alpha}*)?")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that would be helpful.

```
public static void process(String rawData) {
    String[] splitData = rawData.split(" ");
    for (String s : splitData) {
        Pattern pNum = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
        Matcher match = pNum.matcher(s);
        if (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(s + ": Not Allowed");
            continue;
        }

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        int count = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        if (count > 1) {
            System.out.println(s + ": Not Allowed");
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + ": Allowed");
        }
    }

}
```

> Output

Australia: Allowed

India#: Allowed

America@!: Not Allowed

America1: Not Allowed

Comment: Why include space in the character class when you know the word (`s`) cannot contain any space (you split on space, remember?)? OP said *"can contain **alphabets** and ONLY one special character"* Alphabet does *not* include digit.

Comment: Do you consider a digit (0-9) to be a *special* character? Digits are usually not classified that way, but your code would allow a single digit. OPs original regex `[\\p{Alpha}\\p{Punct}]` entirely excludes digits.

Comment: Latest update will give the right result, but it's a lot of code, considering a [single regex can do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38530100/5221149). But, if you want to do it that way, you should remove `CASE_INSENSITIVE` from the digit test, and move the `compile()` calls outside the loop.

Comment: True. I will have a look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple negative look-ahead:

```
((?!\\p{Punct}{2}).)*
```

So your code becomes simply:

```
public void process(String rawData) {
    if (input.matches("((?!\\p{Punct}{2}).)*"))
        System.out.println("Allowed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not allowed");
    }
}
```

The regex just asserts that each character is not a `{Punct}` followed by another `{Punct}`.

Answer (score -1):

Alright! edit again

You can use following regex

```
^[A-Za-z]*[!"\#$%&'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]?[A-Za-z]*$
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/sP9bQ0/3)

This will work for only one punctuation residing at any place.

Comment: `\w` includes `_` and digits (0-9), which is not what OP wants. Also, you pattern only matches if special character is at the end, not embedded in the middle.

Comment: @Andreas: The question isn't clear on the latter point.  The text doesn't say anything about position, but in the examples the special characters *are* always at the end.  Change the `\w+` to `[A-Za-z]+`, and this answer might be exactly right.

Comment: Question says *"can **contain** alphabets and ONLY one special character."* The word "contain" means anywhere, not just at end.

Comment: @Andreas Now you can test the regex :)

Comment: Nope. That matches `Th1s_1s_rea11y_bad!`, which is obviously shouldn't.

Comment: Why list all those special characters, when `\p{Punct}` does the same so succinctly?